# selenium-side-runner does not run Selenium IDE script

Tags: selenium, ide, salesforce, selenium-side-runner

We are recording test scripts with Selenium IDE on a salesforce website without lightning. Tests run fine in selenium IDE but when we try using selenium side runner it fails. It cannot locate element by linkText.